# Why is my Script not operating in the background?

Tags: ruby

I recognize that it is possible to run a script in the background if the code is encompassed by the syntax:

```
job1 = fork do
    # functional code in script
end
Process.detach(job1)
```

Now I have attempted this format on many occasions and it has worked on each occasion to successfully place the script in the background, so that it does not terminate when the Terminal window is closed, however for this particular script (too large to include), it stubbornly remains tethered to its window, and terminates when that window is closed.

This makes no sense, so my questions:

- Is there any Ruby programming construct which could keep a program tethered to a window and in the foreground? e.g. `print` function, which requires a window to print to (so may possibly effect things).
- Is there a better alternative to the above-mentioned format for placing a script in the background, using code within that script.

Comment: Is there anything in your parent script which is waiting for the child to exit ?

Comment: No there is not, all code in the script is encompassed by "job1 = fork do" and "Process.detatch(job1)"